# Помогите перевести в рабочую переменную

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Добрый день! Разбираюсь в друпал базе данных нашел в ней поле BLOB вывожу на экран вижу такое вот чудо.

```
a:3:{s:4:"body";a:1:{s:3:"und";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:5:"value";s:2707:" ";s:7:"summary";s:0:"";s:6:"format";s:13:"filtered_html";s:10:"safe_value";s:2718:" ";s:12:"safe_summary";s:0:"";}}}s:11:"field_image";a:1:{s:3:"und";a:4:{i:0;a:13:{s:3:"fid";s:5:"16212";s:3:"uid";s:1:"1";s:8:"filename";s:12:"_MG_2114.JPG";s:3:"uri";s:21:"public://_MG_2114.JPG";s:8:"filemime";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";s:6:"563111";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:9:"timestamp";s:10:"1469520730";s:11:"rdf_mapping";a:0:{}s:3:"alt";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:5:"width";s:4:"1024";s:6:"height";s:3:"768";}i:1;a:13:{s:3:"fid";s:5:"16213";s:3:"uid";s:1:"1";s:8:"filename";s:12:"_MG_2138.JPG";s:3:"uri";s:21:"public://_MG_2138.JPG";s:8:"filemime";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";s:6:"520561";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:9:"timestamp";s:10:"1469520730";s:11:"rdf_mapping";a:0:{}s:3:"alt";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:5:"width";s:4:"1024";s:6:"height";s:3:"768";}i:2;a:13:{s:3:"fid";s:5:"16214";s:3:"uid";s:1:"1";s:8:"filename";s:12:"_MG_2193.JPG";s:3:"uri";s:21:"public://_MG_2193.JPG";s:8:"filemime";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";s:6:"416441";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:9:"timestamp";s:10:"1469520730";s:11:"rdf_mapping";a:0:{}s:3:"alt";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:5:"width";s:4:"1024";s:6:"height";s:3:"768";}i:3;a:13:{s:3:"fid";s:5:"16215";s:3:"uid";s:1:"1";s:8:"filename";s:12:"_MG_2260.JPG";s:3:"uri";s:21:"public://_MG_2260.JPG";s:8:"filemime";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";s:6:"369226";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:9:"timestamp";s:10:"1469520730";s:11:"rdf_mapping";a:0:{}s:3:"alt";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:5:"width";s:4:"1024";s:6:"height";s:3:"768";}}}s:10:"field_tags";a:0:{}}
```

Сначала я подумал что это json строка но перевести в массив мне ее не удалось. Подскажите как можно перекодировать это в работоспособную php переменную массив к примеру.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через функцию [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) выведите это поле и будет на выходе массив данных.

Использовать просто:

```
$result = unserialize($field);
var_dump($result); // массив данных в вашем случае
```

Comment: К сожалению массив не выходит ...

Comment: @alexsis20102 не то написал, попробуйте unserialize, эта строка уже сериализована

Comment: Спасибо уже добрался сам до unserialize() все сработало спасибо огромное за подсказанное направление !.